# How do I add a list of values for a parameter to a group of dataframes, where that parameter has a different value for each dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 15 samples that each have a unique value of a parameter `L`.
Each sample was tested and provided data which I have placed into separate DataFrames in Pandas.
Each of the DataFrames has a different number of rows, and I want to place the corresponding value of `L` in each row, i.e. create a column for parameter `L`.
Note that `L` is constant in its respective DataFrame.

Is there a way to write a loop that will take a value of `L` from a list containing all of its values, and create a column in its corresponding sample data DataFrame?

I have so far been copying and pasting each line, and then updating the values and DataFrame names manually, but I suppose that this is not the most effective way of using python/pandas!

Most of the code I have used so far has been based on what I have found online, and my actual understanding of it is quite limited but I have tried to comment where possible.

**UPDATED based on first suggested answer.**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob
from os.path import join

path = r'file-directory/'
data_files = glob(join(path + '*.txt'))

def main():
    from contextlib import ExitStack

    with ExitStack() as context_manager: # Allows python to access different data folders
        files = [context_manager.enter_context(open(f, "r")) for f in data_files]
        # Define an empty list and start reading data files
        df1 = []
        for file in files:
            df = pd.read_csv(file,
                encoding='utf-8',
                skiprows=114,
                header=0,
                # names=heads,
                skipinitialspace=True,
                sep='\t'
                )

            # Process the dataframe to remove unwanted rows and columns, and rename the headers
            df = df[df.columns[[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 28]]]
            df = df.drop(0, axis=0)
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
            df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df, heads)), inplace=True)
            for columns in df:
                df[columns] = pd.to_numeric(df[columns], errors='coerce')

            # Append each new dataframe to a new row in the empty dataframe
            df1.append(df)

        # Extract dataframes from list
        data1_0 = df1[0]
        data1_1 = df1[1]
        data1_2 = df1[2]
        data1_3 = df1[3]
        data1_4 = df1[4]
        data1_5 = df1[5]
        data1_6 = df1[6]
        data1_7 = df1[7]
        data1_8 = df1[8]
        data1_9 = df1[9]
        data1_10 = df1[10]
        data1_11 = df1[11]
        data1_12 = df1[12]
        data1_13 = df1[13]
        data1_14 = df1[14]

        # Add in a new column for values of 'L'
        L = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7', 'L8', 'L9', 'L10', 'L11', 'L12', 'L13', 'L14']
        data1_0['L'] = L[0]
        data1_1['L'] = L[1]
        data1_2['L'] = L[2]
        data1_3['L'] = L[3]
        data1_4['L'] = L[4]
        data1_5['L'] = L[5]
        data1_6['L'] = L[6]
        data1_7['L'] = L[7]
        data1_8['L'] = L[8]
        data1_9['L'] = L[9]
        data1_10['L'] = L[10]
        data1_11['L'] = L[11]
        data1_12['L'] = L[12]
        data1_13['L'] = L[13]
        data1_14['L'] = L[14]
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   sys.exit(main())
```

The method I am using (copy and paste lines) works so far, it's just that it doesn't seem to be the most efficient use of my time or the tools I have, and I don't really know how to approach this one with my limited experience of python so far.

I also have several other parameters and datasets that I need to do this for, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do just `data1_0['L'] = L0` and so on for the rest of DataFrames. Given a single value on such assignment will fill the whole column with that value automatically, no need to compute length/index.

Untested code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob
from os.path import join

path = r'file-directory/'
data_files = glob(join(path + '*.txt'))

def main():
    from contextlib import ExitStack

    with ExitStack() as context_manager: # Allows python to access different data folders
        files = [context_manager.enter_context(open(f, "r")) for f in data_files]
        # Define an empty list and start reading data files
        df1 = []
        for file in files:
            df = pd.read_csv(file,
                encoding='utf-8',
                skiprows=114,
                header=0,
                # names=heads,
                skipinitialspace=True,
                sep='\t'
                )

            # Process the dataframe to remove unwanted rows and columns, and rename the headers
            df = df[df.columns[[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 28]]]
            df = df.drop(0, axis=0)
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
            df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df, heads)), inplace=True)
            for columns in df:
                df[columns] = pd.to_numeric(df[columns], errors='coerce')

            # Add file name as identifier
            df['FNAME'] = os.path.basename(file.name)
            # Append each new dataframe to a new row in the empty dataframe
            df1.append(df)

        # Concatenate the results into single dataframe
        data = pd.concat(df1)

        L = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7', 'L8', 'L9', 'L10', 'L11', 'L12', 'L13', 'L14']

        # Supposing number of files and length of L is the same
        repl_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip([os.path.basename(file.name) for file in files], L)}

        # Add the new column
        data1['L'] = data.FNAME.map(repl_dict)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying each line with that suggestion - but how would I implement a loop (if possible)?

Comment: Your code is not complete in terms of how you create those 15 dataframes. Ideally, you keep just one dataframe for all samples and select needed sample with a mask `df.loc[df.L == 'L0']` and such. I suppose the structure of them is the same (column names).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've updated to show how the DataFrames are created - I've tried not to make it too detailed but I was afraid of getting rid of too much in case it is needed.

Comment: Thanks - although I'm afraid that I'm having a problem with the lines containing `os.path.basename(file)`. The error reads 'expected str, bytes or os.Pathlike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: A quick look online tells me that the error is simply that it's looking for one type of object but it is seeing another.

I can understand what that line is supposed to do, i.e. for each file `file`, use the given name as an identifier in `df1`. Although I can't understand why `file` does not work here - do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I've made an edit as file is io.TextIOWrapper, try its .name attribute